# loading jqueryUI dialog() function on WordPress page

Tags: wordpress, jquery-ui, dialog

I am making my first, basic attempt to make a popup window JavaScript for a WordPress site.  I'm using jQueryUI's dialog() function.  My expected behavior is that a popup would appear when the page loads, but this is not happening. I am using the basic example from http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#default

I made a test html page with a div that the jQuery can grab:

`<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>`

My jQueryUI script code is just this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();

});
```

I've saved this script to a file `popup.js`.

I then enqueued the script using the following code, which works fine, as I can see the script in the HTML source of my web page:

```
function my_popup_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'my-popup-script',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/popup.js',
        array( 'jquery' )
    );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_popup_script' );
```

I'm not sure where in this process I'm making an error.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: do you have a link to share? if not (localhost install etc.) check your browser console log after the page load, do you have any errors?

Comment: Sorry, yes the link is 
http://dev.greenbee-web.com/lanwt/joe-test-jquery-popup-page/

I think the problem is I don't have a second JavaScript function that explicitly opens the dialog.  I thought the dialog would open by itself, since a dialog's "autoOpen" defaults to "true", but from the examples I've read, there is always a second JavaScript function, usually with a button, to open the dialog.  
But...I'm still lost.  Do you think I'm on the right track with a second JavaScript function to explicitly open the dialog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's only a [jquery conflict](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/), try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery( "#dialog" ).dialog();

});
```

you can use the jquery noConflict function if you want to use the jquery object as a $ sign, just put this line before all the jquery code:

```
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
```

If you want it to Popup on click event so you can use:

```
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('.the_button').click(function(){     
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
    });    
});
```

Comment: Yes you are right, that fixed it.  Now the popup loads when the page loads.  However, now that I have the basics working, I'd really like to make the popup window load only after clicking a button.  Should I edit this question with my updated JavaScript code, or start an entirely new question?

Comment: I'd upvote your answer, but my rep is only 13.  I need 15 to upvote.